# Random pause of 2 to 5 seconds between requests Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to make a random pause of 2 to 5 seconds between requests. I suppose, that it is a constant timer with such settings as ${__Random(2000,5000)}. I can't understand where should I create this timer: in thread group after all requests, or after every request in thread group? How can I check via listeners, that timer works correctly?

Thanks to Amol, I understood, that my config doesn't work with multiple threads.

So I need 10 threads and 10 iterations with a random pause of 2 to 5 seconds between requests.

Comment: Does your thread-group have only one request?

Comment: There are several requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a random pause between every request, you need to add timer as 'sibling' to your samplers [requests], that means add constant timer as a child to `thread-group`.

How to use Constant Timer for random pause-

[image]

It won't make any difference if you add it as a first child or after all samplers. For better understanding, I suggest you to read [scoping in Jmeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

Example here:-

[image]

You can easily see the randomness requests being made using [`View Results in Table`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table). it has `Start Time` column which gives idea.
I have used [`debug sampler`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) for example again:

[image]

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:-

If I disable the `constant-timer`, I can see all the request being made in the span of 1ms:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Amol. How can I check that timer works correctly? If I check "View Results in Table" I can see, that all request go without configured random pause.

Comment: @DenisFilatov : Are you facing any issue?

Comment: If number of threads 1, it works correctly. If number of threads 10, I can see similar behavior as on 4th screen.

Comment: That can happen as scoping is on `thread-group`, In the above example, we are saying that all the request in the **same** thread group should have some random pause time between 2 to 5 seconds, we are not talking about multiple threads.

Comment: If you want to control the behaviour on multiple thread level, I suggest you to use `Ramp Up`

Comment: If I config Ramp Up as ${__Random(2000,5000)}, requests of the first thread gowithout pause, the second thread doesn't go.

Comment: AFAIK, Ramp-up has to be fixed and even if you use the function it won't make any difference as all the thread creation happens once and whatever value it is will be used till plan gets executed. The thread is not kicking in for you because ramp-up accepts time in seconds and you are passing around an hour as parameter. you are assuming it is `ms` instead of `s`.

Comment: Changing config of Rump Up time to ${__Random(2,5)} doesn't solve this case.